# get content issue in xamarin ios push notification

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

i have an azure push notification with xamarin forms.

this is my message template

```
public class PushTemplates
{
    public class Generic
    {
        public const string Android = "{ \"notification\": { \"title\" : \"PushDemo\", \"body\" : \"$(alertMessage)\"}, \"data\" : { \"action\" : $(alertNotification) } }";
        public const string iOS = "{ \"aps\" : {\"alert\" : \"$(alertMessage)\"}, \"action\" : $(alertNotification) }";
    }

    public class Silent
    {
        public const string Android = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\" : \"$(alertMessage)\", \"action\" : \"$(alertNotification)\"} }";
        public const string iOS = "{ \"aps\" : {\"content-available\" : 1, \"apns-priority\": 5, \"sound\" : \"\", \"badge\" : 0}, \"message\" : \"$(alertMessage)\", \"action\" : \"$(alertNotification)\" }";
    }
}
```

Now i am trying to get this action data when user click push notification in ios. I tried it from this code. I am getting userinfo details But action value is null always.

```
 void ProcessNotificationActions(NSDictionary userInfo)
        {
                string title;
                if (null != userInfo && userInfo.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
                {
                    NSDictionary aps = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;
                    if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("action")))
                    title = (aps[new NSString("action")] as NSString).ToString();
                }
        }
```

Comment: Check out this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms#set-up-push-notification-services-and-) may help you.

Comment: @Wen xu Li thanks. i am already using it

Answer (score 0):

I found answer my self

```
var data = NSJsonSerialization.Serialize(userInfo["action"],NSJsonWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, out error);
var jsonString = NSString.FromData(data, NSStringEncoding.UTF8).ToString();
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationData>(jsonString);
var pushPageName = model.Notification[0].PageName.ToString();
```